# No output box shown in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I have tried to write a simple code on netbean , But on the bottom side of it , only shows `Finished building Javaapplication(run)` .

main question is the output `console box` is disappeared .how can i bring it back ?

[image]

Comment: Try going to `Window -> Reset Windows`

Comment: @MadProgrammer Can you explain what has happened

Comment: Sometimes we close windows and Netbeans doesn't always provide the easiest way to re-open them

Comment: @ MadProgrammer  Is it a Netbeans bug?

Comment: I wouldn't call it a "bug", maybe just annoying from time to time

Comment: @MadProgrammer But I use ur way that clear all my window settings .Any other proper ways

Comment: Don't close the output window

Comment: @MadProgrammer I never clsoe the output window .But it closes automatically when the pgm is not running .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

press `ctrl` + `4` to output window appear , after that run the code using `shift` + `F6` and see the result

Comment: I press window-->Output . The output box has not shown

Comment: what happens after doing it ?

Comment: exact the same screenshot that you've sent ?

Comment: what happens when you hit shift+F6 ?

Comment: `Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); int n = in.nextInt();`

Comment: then tell me what happens

Comment: on the right bottom ,it shows a progress bar that illustrates  Javaapplication project is running

Comment: click on it , it will open the output tab

Comment: still no effect .I reboot the NETBEANS . It works .I guess it should be program clash . Anyway ,for courtesy ,thanks